# Retrieve the columns before a table is populated

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a fresh table

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :engine mysql :dbuser org :database grocer
create table Suppliers (
supplier_id char(10) not null,
supplier_name char(50) not null,
supplier_address char(50),
supplier_city char(50),
supplier_state char(50),
supplier_zip char(10),
supplier_country char(50));
#+END_SRC
```

Before populate it with data, view it as

```
mysql> select * from Suppliers;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

but get no valuable info

How could I retrieve the columns of an empty table?

```
mysql> show columns from Suppliers;
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| supplier_id      | char(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| supplier_name    | char(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| supplier_address | char(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| supplier_city    | char(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| supplier_state   | char(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| supplier_zip     | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| supplier_country | char(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| supplier_phone   | char(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM Suppliers `

Comment: ty @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ, it works and I updated the answer, could you please transmit your comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to show the table column information. use below query.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM Suppliers
```